# How get public address from State Root leaf node (code inside)?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, addresses, state-trie, merkle-patricia-tries

In [article "Understanding the ethereum trie"](https://easythereentropy.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/understanding-the-ethereum-trie/)is written that:

> For the state trie, the keys are ethereum addresses.

So i obtain State Trie and in that trie I got Merkle Leaf node:

```
['9:', ' LEAF      ']
    Node place in DB (raw) : �|\n���0�)�6ed��/���}5�<�+P�-��
    Node place in DB (hash): f87c0a7fa396f130d62912c4366564efc72f94fa937d35b13cbc2b50b92df5d0
    Node data  in DB (raw) : �q� "�cA]{�C����u��^b-�3j}��Q;�d_�N�L��\rඳ�d�V��U���E���n[H��l��b/��c�!���F��#<�~}������Sʂ';{��]��p
    Node data  in DB (data): [' "\xfdcA]{\xc4C\x9e\x96\x91\xb0u\x0e\xce\x04\xb1^b-\xc53j}\xff\xf6Q;\xdad_', "\xf8L\x80\x88\r\xe0\xb6\xb3\xa7d\x00\x00\xa0V\xe8\x1f\x17\x1b\xccU\xa6\xff\x83E\xe6\x92\xc0\xf8n[H\xe0\x1b\x99l\xad\xc0\x01b/\xb5\xe3c\xb4!\xa0\xc5\xd2F\x01\x86\xf7#<\x92~}\xb2\xdc\xc7\x03\xc0\xe5\x00\xb6S\xca\x82';{\xfa\xd8\x04]\x85\xa4p"]

        Unpacking merkle tree node from DB data:
        Key    : 2022fd63415d7bc4439e9691b0750ece04b15e622dc5336a7dfff6513bda645f (this is wallet?)
        Data 0 : 
        Data 1 : 0de0b6b3a7640000 (250 Eth)
        Data 2 : 56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421
        Data 3 : c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470
```

When i open my local private blockchain in Geth, i really see that address

> 0x234132b22de7037e50b9fc4ebd7476315647869e

has

> 250 Eth

So i thing, that output key in my code:

> 2022fd63415d7bc4439e9691b0750ece04b15e622dc5336a7dfff6513bda645f

is that address

> 0x234132b22de7037e50b9fc4ebd7476315647869e

But i din't know how to get from 2022fd6... hash 0x23413... wallet.
How to do that?